# Cómo RE abrir una notificación en android?

Tags: android, terminal

Me llegó una promo por notificación. La abrí y la app se tildó, por lo que no pude ver la promo. Revisando la app no está, ni tiene centro de notificaciones.

Quisiera re abrir esa notificación. Hay alguna manera?
Tengo el registro de notificación con algunos datos.

Se podra hacer algo con la terminal y esos datos? O hay manera de re ejecutar esa notificación? Gracias

Answer (score 0):

**No hay forma de reenviar la notificación, ya que desde el dispositivo no se tiene este control, eso lo realiza Google.**

**En algunos dispositivos se puede visualizar un registro de notificaciones pero no en todos los modelos.** Para poder visualizar el registro de notificaciones tienes que ingresar a los "Widgets", en el Widget de configuración presiona en "Ajustes" ("Settings") y podrás ver en el listado el Notification Log.

Esto por ejemplo es una forma de [visualizar el registro de notificaciones en dispositivos 4.x](https://www.xatakandroid.com/tutoriales/como-ver-historial-notificaciones-android) :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto en dispositivos más recientes, [donde abres los Widgets y en su configuración abres el Notification Log](https://www.theverge.com/2018/10/19/18001608/android-notification-history-how-to-view).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]